# Что и как использовать вместо List<NameValuePair>?

Tags: java, android

Такое дело. Недавно задал вопрос: Как отправить POST запрос на сервер. В ответ мне прислали это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/2971719 . Но в этом ответе используется устаревший List. Чем и как его можно заменить?

Comment: Это с каких пор, 'List' стал устаревшим? Ну а вообще можете использовать 'Map'

Comment: В API version 22 android 5.1.1. Вот ссылка: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html

Comment: @ДимаРодионов в этой же ссылку, которую вы указали, сказано что использовать и как использовать. Вообще, если вам нужен аналог NameValuePair, можете использовать AbstractMap.SimpleEntry

Comment: В ссылке говорится, что устарел NameValuePair, но не List.